# Display image format base64

Tags: javascript, dart

I've some problem with this issue., I want to display image.. but it not..

`logoSrc` in format **base64**

Issue code

```
footerLogos(logoSrc) {
    var logos = "";
    logos += '<tr>';
    logos += '<td style="width: 1120px;">';
    logos += '<div style="display: flex;align-items: center;font-weight: bold;font-family: arial;font-size: 15px;">';
    logos += '</div>';
    logos += '</td>';

    logos += '<td align="center" width="30" id="footerLogo1">';
    logos += '<img src="{{logoSrc}}"  height="30"/>';
    logos += '</td>';
    logos += '</tr>';
    return logos;
}
```

Comment: Does your `logoSrc` look like `data:image/png;base64,SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==` or like `SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==`? If it's the latter, what format is the image (png, jpg, gif, etc.)

Comment: it start with `SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==`

Comment: image format png

Comment: Why is this tagged with both `javascript` and `dart`?  Which is it?

Comment: I'm using javascript in dart

Comment: I don't see any combination of Dart and JavaScript here.  If you mean that you're *transpiling* Dart to JavaScript, then you are writing Dart (and the compiler is generating JavaScript from it); using the `javascript` tag for that is confusing and misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your just have base64 data, you need to tell the html that it should be read as a URL. You also need to pass in the variable itself, wrapped in `${}` instead of `{{}}` and `backticks` instead of 'single quotes' because that's [how JavaScript does template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
footerLogos(logoSrc) {
    var logos = "";
    logos += '<tr>';
    logos += '<td style="width: 1120px;">';
    logos += '<div style="display: flex;align-items: center;font-weight: bold;font-family: arial;font-size: 15px;">';
    logos += '</div>';
    logos += '</td>';

    logos += '<td align="center" width="30" id="footerLogo1">';
    logos += `<img src="data:image/png;base64,${logoSrc}" height="30"/>`;
    logos += '</td>';
    logos += '</tr>';
    return logos;
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution. I just want to point out the use of the backticks on the line beginning with logos += `<img src...

Comment: OP seems to be writing Dart, so the relevant point is that `{{}}` is not how *Dart* does template strings (usually referred to as "string interpolation").

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to revisit the logoSrc and its usage.

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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"
>
```